# NavigationControllerのデフォルトで出てくる戻るボタンでUnwindSegueを利用したい

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

UIButtonを使用してのUnwindSegueを実行する方法については理解できたのですが、
NavigationControllerの左上に(勝手に)表示される戻るボタン(「＜ メニュー」のように表示されるボタン)のタップでUnwindSegueを実行する方法が分かりません。
そもそもそれが可能なのかも分かりませんが、何か方法がありましたら教えてください。
あるいは、ナビゲーションの左上に自前の戻るボタンを配置して、そのボタンでUnwindするしかないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: NavigationControllerで自動で表示される戻るボタンをタップすることで、前の画面に戻れるので、特にUnwind Segueを使わなくても良いと思うのですが、どういった用途を想定されていますか？例えば、一気にトップ画面に戻りたいといったことでしょうか？

Comment: A画面からB画面へ遷移し、B画面からA画面に戻る時に何かしらの引数を渡したいと考えています。B画面にNavigationControllerの戻るボタン以外に、戻る処理(pop)を実装したUIButtonが別にあった場合でも、同じA画面側の処理(unwind)が呼べれば理想的だなと考えました。

Comment: 説明ありがとうございます。なるほど。画面間での値渡しに関する質問ですね。幾つか方法があると思います。例えば、『NSUserDefaultsを利用する』、『カスタムデリゲートメソッドを作成する』などです。一応、UnwindSegueをカスタム化して実装することはできると思いますが、UINavigationControllerを用いるケースにおいては、あまりメジャーな方法ではない気がします。